# JDBC lost connection while iterating ResultSet

Tags: spring, jdbc, resultset, jdbctemplate

In my application I connect to MSSQL database via TCP/IP using Spring and JdbcDAOSupport. It works fine when the connection is stable, but when I unplug the ethernet cable while iterating through the result set the application suspends. It doesn't throw any exceptions.

```
JdbcTemplate jdbc = getJdbcTemplate();
return jdbc.query(sql, mapper, someArgs);
```

where mapper is my own RowMapper class. I have tried using Connection and PreparedStatement and it doesn't solve the problem. Does anybody have any solution for this or have similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application hangs, because TCP/IP was designed with bad connections in mind. When a packet doesn't reach its destination, the sender simply retries with an exponential back-off. If this behavior is not desirable, you configure the socket blocking timeout (SO_TIMEOUT).

Unfortunately, the SQL Server JDBC driver does not have an option to configure the socket timeout, so it will block indefinitely.

As Nathan Hughes indicates in his comment, the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) does have an option to configure a socketTimeout, so you could try that driver instead.

Comment: maybe try jtds? looks like it has a socket timeout (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: @NathanHughes That is probably the only option, yes

Comment: @Falcon: not loginTimeout, i think. did you see this entry (farther down on the faq page): socketTimeout (default - 0)
    The amount of time to wait (in seconds) for a server response before timing out.

Comment: This explanation really helped to diagnose a tricky issue, thanks very much!